# KQL reformat table add columns based on distinct values in column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm looking for a smart way in Kusto Query Language (KQL) to reformat a table. One Column (in this example Car-column) gives the kind of new rows. So I'm looking for a KQL pipe command to add columns and reduce the number of rows by reordering the content.

E.g. I would like to format this example table:

| Distance | avg. Velocity | Car |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Audi |
| 0 | 0 | VW |
| 0 | 0 | Porsche |
| 200 | 60 | Audi |
| 200 | 55 | VW |
| 200 | 70 | Porsche |
| 400 | 63 | Audi |
| 400 | 54 | VW |
| 400 | 77 | Porsche |

to look like this:

| Distance | Audi | VW | Porsche |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 60 | 55 | 70 |
| 400 | 63 | 54 | 77 |

Is there a good (maybe one line) kql-cmd to get to this result?

Background information: After an Azure Digital Twins Query, joined with a Azure Data Explorer table and some piped commands, I get Table 1, but I want to plot the data as seperate graphes in one grafana diagram. Therefore I need the data as shown in Table 2. Currently I use hard coded car names e.g. '| where Car = "Audi"' and join columns together... That's not efficient nor reusable. There must be a better way!

I'm looking forward for your answers :)
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for your question is to use the [pivot plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin)

for example:

```
datatable(Distance:long, avg_Velocity:long, Car:string)
[
    0, 0, "Audi", 
    0, 0, "VW", 
    0, 0, "Porsche", 
    200, 60, "Audi", 
    200, 55, "VW", 
    200, 70, "Porsche", 
    400, 63, "Audi", 
    400, 54, "VW", 
    400, 77, "Porsche", 
]
| evaluate pivot(Car, avg(avg_Velocity))
```

| Distance | Audi | Porsche | VW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 60 | 70 | 55 |
| 400 | 63 | 77 | 54 |

However, you should be able to chart the original table in Grafana as is by specifying the series columns correctly for the specific chart that you need. I don't have Grafana around but here is how it would be in the Azure Data Explorer Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I regret never studying kql pivot plugin :D